# Maintain Scroll position listview on viewpager fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

I am trying to maintain scroll position of ListView inside a Fragment which is in ViewPager

> **Issue :** The `onCreateView` and `onResume` method is called before Fragment is loaded in ViewPager , hence I have also tried using `setUserVisibleHint` but still my ViewPager Fragment is not restoring the ListView scroll position.

Code :

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d(TAG, "inside onPause");
    Constant.index = mExamsListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    View v = mExamsListView.getChildAt(0);
    Constant.top = (v == null) ? 0 : (v.getTop() - mExamsListView
            .getPaddingTop());
}


 @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        Log.d(TAG, "inside setUserVisibleHint");
        Log.d(TAG, "inside setUserVisibleHint : Constant.index = "
                + Constant.index + "  Constant.top = " + Constant.top);
        if (null != mExamsListView)
            mExamsListView.setSelectionFromTop(Constant.index, Constant.top);
    }
```

`Constant.top` and `Constant.index` are global constants.

I need a direction where i can figure-out this behavior.

Comment: if you post your fragment also then issue will be more visible

Comment: @AmrutBidri this is what i did for maintaining scroll position , rest of code is bit big , hence cannot post uncessaru

Comment: don't really get why you can't restore state in on resume? I'm guessing that you do this after you set the adapter, right? And judging from your loggs, I take it that you have verified that you save the scroll position?

Comment: @Qw4z1 the onresume is called before fargment is actually visible in viewpager